# Compare button's background image to another image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, compare, background-image

I am creating a WPF project in C#. I have a `button`, whose `background image` I want to change when the `button` is clicked. However, first, I want to compare the current `background image` of the `button` to another one and then change it. This is my code:

```
private void homeLightsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //image for Lights ON
            Uri lightsOn = new Uri("images/homeLightsOn.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(lightsOn);
            BitmapFrame temp = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
            var brush = new ImageBrush();
            brush.ImageSource = temp;

            //image for Lights OFF
            Uri lightsOff = new Uri("images/homeLightsOff.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
            StreamResourceInfo streamInfo1 = Application.GetResourceStream(lightsOff);
            BitmapFrame temp1 = BitmapFrame.Create(streamInfo.Stream);
            var brush1 = new ImageBrush();
            brush1.ImageSource = temp1;

            if (homeLightsButton.Background == brush)
            {
                homeLightsButton.Background = brush1;
            }
            else
            {
                homeLightsButton.Background = brush;
            }
        }
```

The problem is inside the `if` statement; from what I understand the way I compare the `background image` to another `image` is wrong. I have searched the forums, but I couldn't find anything. Any ideas?

Comment: How could this possibly work? You are comparing `homeLightsButton.Background` to a newly created ImageBrush instance. That comparison will always return `false`. Besides that, why are you creating a BitmapFrame in such a strange way? In WPF, you typically set the **Build Action** of an image file (in a Visual Studio project) to **Resource**, and load it by a [Resource File Pack URI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx), like `var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/images/homeLightsOn.jpg"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply store the two ImageBrushes as XAML Resources

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="homeLightsOn" ImageSource="images/homeLightsOn.jpg"/>
    <ImageBrush x:Key="homeLightsOff" ImageSource="images/homeLightsOff.jpg"/>
</Window.Resources>

...
<Button Background="{StaticResource homeLightsOff}"
        Click="homeLightsButton_Click"/>
```

and write your Click handler like this:

```
private void homeLightsButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    button.Background = button.Background == Resources["homeLightsOff"]
        ? (ImageBrush)Resources["homeLightsOn"]
        : (ImageBrush)Resources["homeLightsOff"];
}
```